# ADF Json File Column count and Flattening all columns in file without data flow

Tags: azure, azure-adf

How to count the number of all column in JSON file using Azure Data Factory activity ?
How to Flatten complete objects(All columns) in JSON file using Azure Data Factory activity?

Answer (score 0):

Upload Json file in blob storage, create dataset after creating linked service to connect the json file, then create data flow with source as the json dataset, in data flow you will find the FLATTEN
step to flatten complex object in JSON